# Backbone view - Cross component communication

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extends({
});
var ComponentView = BaseView.extends({
});
var ChildView1 = ComponentView.extends({
});
var ChileView2 = ComponentView.extends({
});
```

I want to a have cross component communication between `ChildView1` and `ChileView2.`

I would like to have `a _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)` obj in the `parent(ComponentView)`.

I saw in some of the examples something like below

```
var ComponentView = BaseView.extends(_.extend({}, Backbone.Events, {
});
```

PS: i am initializing all the components from another BackboneView using an attribute present on the components

Answer (score 2):

In Backbone, I prefer using some sort of publish/subscribe event pattern to communicate between views. In it's most simplest form, your code will look something like the following:

```
/* Create an Event Aggregator for our Pub/Sub */
var eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

/* Pass that Event Aggregator to our Child Views */
var childView1 = new ChildView1({ "eventAggregator": eventAggregator });

/* From here we can just bind/trigger off of eventAggregator whenever we need */
eventAggregator.bind("tellChild", function(e) { alert(e.message); });
eventAggregator.trigger("tellChild", { "message": "hello" });
```

Notice how we are creating a new object that extends off of the built in `Backbone.Events` and passing it into the `ChildView1`. Inside of the ChildView or anywhere else that has a reference to eventAggregator you can bind/trigger new events. However, this is the tip of the iceberg as you will need to handle no longer needing to know about this event handler, unbinding the event handler and ensuring you're not leaking memory.

There isn't enough space here to go deep into this, so I would recommend reading more about event aggregation in Backbone. All of my logic that I have ever used is derived from the work that Derick Bailey wrote in [blog posts](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) and his book "[Building Backbone Plugins](https://leanpub.com/building-backbone-plugins)" (both excellence sources of information). These came ultimately from his work in creating [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com), which is a nice compliment to Backbone. If you don't want to have to worry about these issues or just want a simpler API, I recommend using [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com) or something equivalent to improve your Backbone Views.

Comment: I agree with this approach. But, I want to keep the event aggregator object in the parentView (i.e ComponentView).

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. Just have ComponentView create the event aggregator and pass into the ChildView1 and ChildView2 when they are created.